# YouTube OAuth: Why do some accounts give me "Invalid Credentials"?

Tags: youtube-api, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm using OmniAuth in Rails to authenticate users through YouTube OAuth.

I have several Google/YouTube accounts. Two of them log in just fine. Two of them fail with "invalid_credentials".

I'm not entirely sure what that error means; it doesn't appear in the [OAuth 2 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).

I'm successfully logged into all four of these accounts on the Google side using multiple sign-in, so it's not that I'm logging in incorrectly. Two of the accounts work, so it's not that my API key is bad.

What's going on?

Comment: There are a number of reasons why "invalid_credentials" comes up. One of them is a set of invalid client ID/client secret. Are these using the same client ID/secret as your other accounts? Also, what happens when you try with a barebones code example instead of a wrapper library like OmniAuth?

Comment: I'm using the same exact setup, including client ID and secret, to log into each account. I'm just clicking log out in my app and then trying to log in as a different Google user. I don't have any experience doing the OAuth flow manually, and I think it would be a time sink to try now.

Comment: I understand that you are under a time constraint, but try this code with those accounts. It's in Python, but if you are any good at Ruby, Python should be easy: https://gist.github.com/ikai/5905078. Try adding an API call to that, which you can pull from our sample code: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python#my_uploads

Comment: Huh. Well, I tried using the Python sample code with the same credentials, and it worked for all my accounts. Now I'm stumped…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've got the answer.

They're returning `invalid_credentials` because there's no YouTube account associated with the user who's trying to log in.

*But!* I did make sure to log into YouTube with those accounts before trying to log into my app. Turns out that's not enough.

In this brave new world, Google users can log into YouTube *without actually creating a YouTube account*. In the YouTube UI, a YouTube account is a "channel". It is now possible to log into YouTube and not have a channel.

To create a channel, click the user menu (represented by your profile picture) in the top-right corner of the page and click "My Channel". You'll be prompted to create one.

Then you can log in with YouTube OAuth.

Comment: That's right! I should have caught on to this earlier. I even wrote a doc referencing the requirement: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/moving_to_oauth. The Python sample working probably was misleading. We'll probably need to look into how we can return a better error message.

Comment: Hi, 5 years too late for this, but I've got a channel and am still getting this error.