# What is the authorization token for the request? (Youtube API)

Tags: php, curl, youtube

I'm trying to follow Google's Youtube API on resumable upload in PHP/Curl before I go full C/Curl. Here is my code.

```
<?php

    $resource           = "www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet,status,contentDetails";
    $query              = '{
      "snippet": {
        "title": "My video title",
        "description": "This is a description of my video",
        "tags": ["cool", "video", "more keywords"],
        "categoryId": 22
      },
      "status": {
        "privacyStatus": "public",
        "embeddable": True,
        "license": "youtube"
      }
    }';

    $response           = NULL;
    
    # Initialize PHP/CURL handle
    $ch                 = curl_init();

    $request_headers    = array();
    $request_headers[]  = 'Authorization: Bearer *****';
    $request_headers[]  = 'Content-Length: 278';
    $request_headers[]  = 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8';
    $request_headers[]  = 'X-Upload-Content-Length: 3000000';
    $request_headers[]  = 'X-Upload-Content-Type: video/*';

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     , $request_headers          );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     , $query                    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST           , TRUE                      );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET        , FALSE                     );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER         , FALSE                     );      // Include head as needed
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY         , FALSE                     );      // Return body
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL            , $resource                 );      // Target site
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE        , TRUE                      );      // Minimize logs
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , FALSE                     );      // No certificate
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , TRUE                      );      // Follow redirects
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , TRUE                      );      // Return in string

    # Create return array
    $response           = curl_exec($ch); 
    $info               = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $error              = curl_error($ch);

    # Close PHP/CURL handle
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;

?>
```

Whenever I run the script I get a 403 Forbidden error. I think the issue comes from the authorization token. I think I'm not using what I am supposed to. Google says

> "The request sets the following HTTP request headers:
>
> - Authorization – The authorization token for the request."

I am not sure what it is exactly, so I used an access token generated with Youtube PHP Client API but still nothing.

Comment: It seems you have just posted your API authentication credentials to a public forum, you'll want to change/revoke them immediately.

Comment: @AlexHowansky thanks, changed already! I thought it only last an hour

Comment: What do you getting exactly along with 403 ?

Comment: @SagarV no (json) body if that's what you are asking. just a plain 403 Forbidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this code. Maybe this can help you.

In this, you can get the location parameter in the response header. Please see below code and response header that I got. Also, use clean and clear `JSON` data in `$requestBody`

```
<?php

function startResumableSession() {
    $requestBody = '{"snippet":{"title":"test video","description":"testing api","tags":["any","thing"],"categoryId":25},"status":{"privacyStatus":"public","embeddable":"true","license":"youtube"}}';
    $headers = array
    (
        "POST /upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet,status HTTP/1.1",
        "Host: www.googleapis.com",
        "Content-length: 0",
        "Content-type: application/json",
        "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxACCESS_TOKENxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    );
    /* Parameter values in the request URL must be URL-encoded. */
    $url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet,status";
    $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,urlencode($requestBody));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "192.168.10.5:8080");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $json = json_decode($result);
    /* debug info */
    return array('response'=>(array)$result,
        'info' => $info,
        'headers'=>$headers
    );
}
```

This is the header of the response. In this, you can find the location with upload id. For next step please visit this link [Save the resumable session URI](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol#Save_Resumable_Session_URI)

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    X-GUploader-UploadID: AEnB2UqLAR0Gf5xGi9pDGEYgMkrajFAuaC33IpiY-2WM2hspQe30DxUz2qzELRenLWOyrK8x9S3He51SXGmHU6olQzUGqGxbcw
    Location: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet,status&upload_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    ETag: "m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/V3uOxfY0pSsHgtj2XMjOGKOAp3o"
    Vary: Origin
    Vary: X-Origin
    X-Goog-Correlation-Id: Z14VW6zFX9E
    Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
    Pragma: no-cache
    Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
    Date: Fri, 16 Jun 2017 08:36:22 GMT
    Content-Length: 0
    Server: UploadServer
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="38,37,36,35"
```

Comment: I get a 400 error code now the message is "Parse Error". Make it work and you'll get the points.

Comment: If I remove everything after` /* Check request body contenttype */` I get a 401 Error Invalid Credentials. Where do I get the auth token?

Comment: @PaikuHan You can have the auth token from https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application

Comment: @PaikuHan for Auth Token: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground


To check Token: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token={access_token}


SOF Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22679147/invalid-credentials-for-oauth-from-youtube-api

Answer (score 1):

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/... is needed now (https:// not just www)

also from youtube api site

In the list of APIs, make sure the status is ON for the YouTube Data API v3.

If your application will use any API methods that require user authorization, read the authentication guide to learn how to implement OAuth 2.0 authorization.